# Displaying a text when JSONArray gives a null value - android

Tags: java, android, arrays

Im getting the data from `JSONArray` and when it is null i need to show a text saying **no data**. Here is the code. I get a error when executing this.

```
 List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_events, "GET", params);

        try {

            events = json.getJSONArray(TAG_EVENTS);

            if(events.length() == 0){


                TextView txno = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.no_events);
                txno.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            }else{
                for (int i = 0; i < events.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = events.getJSONObject(i);

                    id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
                    venue = c.getString(TAG_VENUE);
                    time = c.getString(TAG_TIME);



                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_DATE, date);
                    map.put(TAG_TIME, time);
                    map.put(TAG_VENUE, venue);


                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    eventList.add(map);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and the error i get is this :

```
04-17 15:55:54.335: E/JSON Parser(6199): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

How to set the text when i receive null value?

Answer (score 3):

Whilst Alex van den Hoogen's answer is correct, I'd like to point out that there are 2 similar methods for extraction of values from `JSONObject`:

- `getJSONArray()` throws an exception if there's no value for such key;
- `optJSONArray()` returns null in this case.

You can make use of the latter one like this:

```
events = json.optJSONArray(TAG_EVENTS);

if (events == null || events.length() == 0) {
    TextView txno = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.no_events);
    txno.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Also I would `return;` after setting the `TextView` which makes for more readable code, but that's just nitpicking :).

Comment: I get an Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject error

Comment: It seems that some other line gives you an exception. Do the same work on `JSONObject c = events.getJSONObject(i);` and other places. Make sure that the elements of `JSONArray` are `JSONObject`s, not `String`s or something else. If it won't fix, tell us on which line of code the error occurs and post your json.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment of `events` in: `events = json.getJSONArray(TAG_EVENTS);` will not work and will throw an exception because there isn't a `JSONArray`.

One way to solve this is to also set your error in the `catch` clause, like so:

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_events, "GET", params);

try {
    events = json.getJSONArray(TAG_EVENTS);

    if(events.length() == 0) {
        throw new JSONException("Content was empty");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < events.length(); i++) {
            id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
            venue = c.getString(TAG_VENUE);
            time = c.getString(TAG_TIME);

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_ID, id);
            map.put(TAG_DATE, date);
            map.put(TAG_TIME, time);
            map.put(TAG_VENUE, venue);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            eventList.add(map);
        }
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    TextView txno = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.no_events);
    txno.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

This also throws an exception when we have no content in `events JSONArray`. But the exception will be caught and show a message that you already have set (I suppose).

Comment: theres a problem in json parser. from there only the exception and error occurs. i checked with log.d dialogs in it after parser it throws an error

Comment: It's an intentional error. And I suppose the JSON parser is correct. Anyway, @Alexander Sukharev answer/addition has a much cleaner solution.